# suggestions to show/hide columns / row sorting / fixed headers in a large data table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a very big table filled with data

1st - i want to use show/hide columns:
the problem is when my columns pass 10-12 to more it got really slow
for this i gave each  a class for the column it is in and call it
for toggle with assocciated anchor().

2nd & 3rd - i want to use fixed headers as my row go way more than 1000's,
as i do this i can not effectively use my search which i wrote it with js
and really is a lightweight code.

PS. plz remember i have a very large json generated table with more than 20 columns and way more than 1000's of rows and i ** CANT USE ANY FRAME WORKS EXCEPT JQUERY AND JQUERYUI **

EDIT: ADDS SOME CODE FOR SHOW/HIDE

```
        $('#columnSelect').on('click', 'li', function(){
        var columnTmp = $(this).children('a').text()
        $('#dataTable').find('.'+columnTmp).toggle()
    })
```

i have a list of my  tags which is also created dynamically with my first ajax call
i got the text of anchor and match it with 
  then toggle that column tds

Comment: Is there any reason you can't take advantage of pagination to keep down the cost of the resources? The fastest way to show/hide rows (performance speaking) is to use `.addClass().removeClass()` chained methods.

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: @ohgodwhy thanks for your response. yes it is asked to be one page of data without pagination for usablity matters

Comment: dear @renjith ! i cheched datatables.net before abd checked it again now. it is a good frame work but dont have all my credentials and necessities

Comment: @Homam you are better off making a well established plugin work for you, even if it means somone write additional extension of it, than trying to reinvent the wheeel. As you are already finding out hanndling large numbers of elements needs to be done properly. Post some of the code that you are using to hide columns

Comment: dear @charlietfl thanks for advice. i pasted some jq codes as example. let me know if that is not enough

Comment: right off try classChange instead as @Ohgodwhy suggested. Also will help if you can cache columns as objects in advance, and if possible. Hate to say this again...better to find a plugin that is close, and adjust it. The number of elements you are talking about will push limits of many browsers, and user hardware too

Comment: have a look to ..jquery easyui ....http://jeasyui.com/index.php.. completly built on jquery and HTML5...and light weight

Comment: @ohgodwhy thanks for your advice about add/remove class it works fantastic

Comment: @charlietfthanks for your advice about add/remove class it works fantastic

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of two plugins for some of my "large tables"

This is used to format the table, provides sorting and other functionality:
http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/

And, this provides filtering, this is fast and very effective, it may well help if you have a lot of columns/data.  Have a search box or drop down discretely at the top of each column which will allow for filtering on that column and a "quick find" type search box which will search/filter across all columns
http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet-table-filter.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are really jQuery lover then I suggest to go with some free jQuery Grid APIs such as Slick Grid or Flexi Grid

Comment: thanks but none of these datagrid frameworks do what i need as i need

Comment: I think Slick Grid and Flexi both has much stuff to do.Your requirements can be accomplished by Modifying the API.It's self. BTW it's open source API so you should know what to do else you can try on your way to develop complete API which can function  as you wish.